# Additive Inverses for a Vector Space with regular vector addition and irregular scalar multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Suppose there exists a set in R2 such that (x,y) +(x',y') = (x+x', y+y') and k(x,y) = (kx,0)

One of the required properties for a set to be a vector space is that there exists an additive inverse -u in the set that when added to a vector in the vector space u equals the additive identity, which I see to be (0,0)

I believe that there isn't such an additive inverse, but I'm not completely sure. Could someone clarify?

Comment: Why don't you think an additive inverse exists? $(x, y) + (-x, -y) = (0, 0)$ after all. Perhaps you're confused by the fact that the inverse of $(x, y)$ is *not* the same as $(-1) \cdot (x, y)$ (which is a problem for being a vector space....).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The additive inverse of $(x, y)$ is $(-x, -y)$. Note that this is **not** the same as the element

$$(-1) \cdot (x, y) = (-x, 0).$$

This, by the way, implies that we do not have a vector space with these operations.

Comment: Oh, so the additive inverse property holds, but the property 1(x,y) = (x,y) fails?

Comment: Right, $1(x, y) \ne (x, y)$ in general.